# Reading dictionary in the list - python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a list like this (coming out of a json file reading):

```py
list = [{'sheet_name': 'Daily', 'id_column': 'A', 'frequency': 'daily'}]
```

I want to read the value of the key 'id_column' but when I use:

```py
list[0]['id_column']
```

it doesnt work

it considers each letter as a index in the list but not the dictionary. So this is what i get when trying to read indexes:

```py
list[0] = [
list[1] = {
```

How can i read the key value in the dictionary in the list.

thanks

Comment: It's not a good practice to override builtins in general. For example, with this approach you won't be able to assign a var as an empty `list()`  later in the code.

Comment: Sounds like your list is a string, rather than an actual list. Check that list isn't actually defined as: '[{'sheet_name': 'Daily', 'id_column': 'A', 'frequency': 'daily'}]'

Comment: It looks like your data `list` is actually a json string. I think it'll work if you `json.loads` your data first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the data you retrieved is in the form of 'String' or 'JsonArray of String'

You can use `json.loads()` python module to convert to actual Python List or Dictionary

```
import json

data = json.loads(list)  
print(data[0]['id_column'])
```

Please refer for more details,
https://pythonexamples.org/python-json-to-list/

**Note**: I notice that you are defined the list name as 'list' it is highly recommended to avoid naming variables or functions which equals python builtins